# Regression by group and display output in python

Tags: python, group-by, regression, coefficients

Hi ~ I want to ask a quick question related to regression analysis in python. I have the following `dataframe`:

```
group      Y        X
 1         9        3
 1         5        4
 1         3        1
 2         1        6
 2         2        4
 2         3        9
```

Y is dependent and X is independent variable. I want to run regression  `Y=a + bx` by group and output another `dataframe` that contains the coefficients, t-stats and R-square. So, the dataframe should be like:

```
group   coefficient   t-stats    intercept    r-square
  1        0.25         1.4        4.3         0.43
  2        0.30         2.4        3.6         0.49
 ...        ...         ...        ...         ...
```

Can someone help ? Many thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Question is too broad. There are many ways to run regressions and run groups off data across multiple Python libraries. Please make an effort from online docs, tutorials, and come back with specific issues. And be sure to include a [MCVE].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will show some mockup so you can build the rest. It is mainly pulling up a your custom regression function and passing the dataframe in using `apply`.

let me know what you think.

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm 

def GroupRegress(data, yvar, xvars):
    Y = data[yvar]
    X = data[xvars]
    X['intercept'] = 1.
    result = sm.OLS(Y, X).fit()
    return result.params

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'group': [1,1,1,2,2,2], 
                   'Y': [9,5,3,1,2,3],
                  'X': [3,4,1,6,4,9]
                  })
df


df.groupby('group').apply(GroupRegress, 'Y', ['X'])
```

Result below:

```
X   intercept
group       
1   1.000000    3.0
2   0.236842    0.5
```

Comment: Thanks MEdwin, I knew how to extract intercepts and coefficients, but I am struggling with getting R-squared and t-stats. I haven't see any post discussing the similar issue. I'd appreciate if you could give some hints. Thanks