# how to run regression on groups with dates

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, regression

I am trying to calculate the regression coefficient of `weight` for every `animal_id` and `cycle_nr` in my df:

| animal_id | cycle_nr | feed_date | weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1003 | 8 | 2020-02-06 | 221 |
| 1003 | 8 | 2020-02-10 | 226 |
| 1003 | 8 | 2020-02-14 | 230 |
| 1004 | 1 | 2020-02-20 | 231 |
| 1004 | 1 | 2020-02-21 | 243 |

What I tried using this source [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56634026/regression-by-group-and-display-output-in-python):

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm 


def GroupRegress(data, yvar, xvars):
    Y = data[yvar]
    X = data[xvars]
    X['intercept'] = 1.
    result = sm.OLS(Y, X).fit()
    return result.params

result = df.groupby(['animal_id', 'cycle_nr']).apply(GroupRegress, 'feed_date', ['weight'])
```

This code fails because my variable includes a date.

What I tried next:

I figured I could create a numeric column to use instead of my date column. I created a simple count_id column:

| animal_id | cycle_nr | feed_date | weight | id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1003 | 8 | 2020-02-06 | 221 | 1 |
| 1003 | 8 | 2020-02-10 | 226 | 2 |
| 1003 | 8 | 2020-02-14 | 230 | 3 |
| 1004 | 1 | 2020-02-20 | 231 | 4 |
| 1004 | 1 | 2020-02-21 | 243 | 5 |

Then I ran my regression on this column

```
result = df.groupby(['animal_id', 'cycle_nr']).apply(GroupRegress, 'id', ['weight'])
```

[image]

The slope calculation looks good, but the intercept makes of course no sense.

Then I realized that this method is only useable when the interval between measurements is regular. In most cases the interval is 7 days, but somethimes it is 10, 14 or 21 days.

I dropped records where the interval was not 7 days and re-ran my regression...It works, but I hate that I have to throw away perfectly fine data.

I'm wondering if there is a better approach where I can either include the date in my regression or can correct for the varying intervals of my dates.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: [Can I plot a linear regression with datetimes on the x-axis with seaborn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308729/can-i-plot-a-linear-regression-with-datetimes-on-the-x-axis-with-seaborn), ... [Regression with Date variable using Scikit-learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16453644/regression-with-date-variable-using-scikit-learn), ... [linear regression for timeseries python (numpy or pandas)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32327471/linear-regression-for-timeseries-python-numpy-or-pandas)

Answer (score 0):

> I'm wondering if there is a better approach where I can either include the date in my regression or can correct for the varying intervals of my dates.

- If the feed dates are strings make a datetime Series using [pandas.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html).
- Use that new Series to calculate the actual time difference between feedings
- Use the resultant [timedeltas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timedeltas.html) in your regression instead of a *linear* *fabricated* sequence. The timedeltas have different attributes, (i.e. microseconds, days), that can be used depending on the resolution you need.

My first instinct would be to *produce* the Timedeltas for each group separately. The first feeding in each group would of course be time zero.

Making the Timedeltas may not even be necessary - there are probably datetime aware regression methods in Numpy or Scipy or maybe even Pandas - I imagine there would have to be, it is a common enough application.

Instead of Timedeltas the datetime Series could be converted to ordinal values for use in the regression.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "feed_date": [
            "2020-02-06",
            "2020-02-10",
            "2020-02-14",
            "2020-02-20",
            "2020-02-21",
        ]
    }
)


>>> q = pd.to_datetime(df.feed_date)
>>> q
0   2020-02-06
1   2020-02-10
2   2020-02-14
3   2020-02-20
4   2020-02-21
Name: feed_date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
>>> q.apply(pd.Timestamp.toordinal)
0    737461
1    737465
2    737469
3    737475
4    737476
Name: feed_date, dtype: int64
>>>
```

Comment: That is actually a good point.  Converting my dates to ordinal values is actually a good solution. I will give that a go. I will also have a look at the time delta solution. I like for my data to remain readible,  so this would be a nice solution. Thanks for your feedback.